# Using GuiceFilter with Jetty WebAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true)

Tags: jetty, guice

I am using `GuiceFilter` under Jetty. Normally everything works fine, but when I enable `WebAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true)` all of a sudden a single HTTP request results in the same filter being invoked twice. Worse, the second invocation uses the same request scope as the first so I get exceptions telling me that I'm trying to use a database connection that has already been closed. What is going on?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tracked this down to human error.

I was registering `GuiceFilter` once using `WebAppContext.addFilter(GuiceFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class))` but I forgot that my project also contained a `WEB-INF/web.xml` file. Jetty was parsing this file and registering a second `GuiceFilter` instance. So the first mistake was registering `GuiceFilter` twice.

Why is this issue only visible when `WebAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true)` is invoked? Well, normally Jetty parses `WEB-INF/web.xml` from within the webapp. Because each webapp has a private ClassLoader, you end up with two instances of the `GuiceFilter` class. Each one gets initialized separately which means your filters get added into separate `GuiceFilter.pipeline` instances.

When `WebAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true)` is invoked, there is only one instance of the GuiceFilter class and your filters get added twice to the **same** pipeline. This means that now your filters will get invoked multiple times per request scope.

To fix the problem, simply remove `WEB-INF/web.xml`.